# OpenCL devices visible only by root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, opencl

I'm on intel + nvidia machine. Trying to run opencl application. Ubuntu 18.04

Just installed opencl-icd, intel-opencl-icd. (cuda was installed long ago. checked, working)

When I run clinfo under user, I get:

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

But sudo clinfo returns full list of platforms.

I've tried to `sudo adduser $USER video` but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I was connected via ssh, so
logout and then login helped

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
sudo adduser $USER render
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.